# Focus-follows-mouse in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, mouse

Is it possible to get focus-follows-mouse behavior in terminal Neovim?

Please note this is different from this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42275/leftmouse-focus-window-without-moving-cursor) about how to focus a window by *clicking* the mouse. This question is about how to focus a window by *moving* the mouse.

By focus-follows-mouse, I mean when the mouse pointer is hovered over a window that is not activated, it should be activated as if I switched to it using e.g. `<C-w><Up>`.

I found the `mousefocus` option which sounds like exactly what I want:

```
'mousefocus' 'mousef'   boolean (default off)
            global
    The window that the mouse pointer is on is automatically activated.
    When changing the window layout or window focus in another way, the
    mouse pointer is moved to the window with keyboard focus.  Off is the
    default because it makes using the pull down menus a little goofy, as
    a pointer transit may activate a window unintentionally.
```

Unfortunately, adding `set mouse=a mousefocus` to my configuration has no effect. Moving the mouse pointer over an unfocused window doesn't do anything. (Having the mouse pointer automatically moved when I do `<C-w><Up>` sounds annoying, but that's not happening either.) I tried this in Kitty and Gnome Terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! In my tests it only works on gVim.

Comment: Voting to close this question as [LeftMouse focus window without moving cursor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42275/leftmouse-focus-window-without-moving-cursor) has better answers.

Comment: Lol, I guess this happens pretty often on stack exchange but the question you've marked this as duplicating is totally unrelated. Would you mind reopening please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vim 9.0 documentation says: only works in the GUI

```
'mousefocus' 'mousef'   boolean (default off)
            global
            {only works in the GUI}
    The window that the mouse pointer is on is automatically activated.
    When changing the window layout or window focus in another way, the
    mouse pointer is moved to the window with keyboard focus.  Off is the
    default because it makes using the pull down menus a little goofy, as
    a pointer transit may activate a window unintentionally.
    MS-Windows: Also see 'scrollfocus' for what window is scrolled when
    using the mouse scroll wheel.
```

Where: "only works on the GUI" means only on gVim (and potentially on nvim-qt but in my experience it does not).

The possibility for nvim-qt to implemented `mousefocus`is only available since 6th of September 2020 (see [issue 12849](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12849) but has not been implemented so far.

Comment: Hmm, OK thanks. I know that mouse hover events are possible, [somehow](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim#hover-events), so maybe we can implement similar functionality in a plugin.

Comment: Should there be an issue open on Neovim to further document this option, or remove it since it doesn't work? According to this [github comment](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12849#issuecomment-687866351) it may be implemented in the backend but not in the UI.

Comment: My understanding is that the backend inform the GUI but the nvim-qt GUI didn't took care so far. You could introduce a demand to nvim-qt.

Comment: Based on what bufferline.nvim is doing, maybe the route to getting this working in the terminal is to use `mousemoveevent` instead of `mousefocus`.