# LeftMouse focus window without moving cursor

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, microsoft-windows, mouse

Is there a way for clicking on a Vim window to focus that window if inactive (without moving the cursor), then move the cursor if the window is already active?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function IsWinFocused()
    return getmousepos().winid==win_getid()
endfunction
noremap <expr> <LeftMouse> IsWinFocused() ? '<LeftMouse>' : '<LeftMouse>`m'
augroup leftMouse
    autocmd!
    au BufLeave * mark m 
augroup end
```

Which leaves a marker behind as you leave a window, then comes back to it after rejoining the window.

But this isn't ideal as you have to have unfocused the window since opening it in order for focusing it to work properly, and if that's not the case it could yeet you into the depths of a file if marker m was in prior use.

Also I'm not a huge fan of seeing the window jump to where I clicked and back every time I focus a window

Edit: using Neovim wrapped in Nvy on Windows 11

Comment: The `mousefocus` option could be interesting for you. Could you tell us more about your use case such that we can propose you the correction solution?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I use scrolloff to center my cursor in the screen, and I don't want the screen to jump around when I use my mouse to focus a window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus-follows-mouse in Neovim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41622/focus-follows-mouse-in-neovim)

Comment: It tells me that `mousefocus` is not the answer, but it doesn't tell me what _is_ the answer. I think I was able to figure out a solution, see my answer below.

Comment: I agree :-) We use that formulation to link questions in order to not spread the answers. But with your answer we should probably link it the other way around ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've figured it out. Here's the mappings I've come up with:

```
noremap <expr> <LeftMouse> getmousepos().winid==win_getid() ? '<LeftMouse>' : '<Cmd>call win_gotoid(getmousepos().winid)<CR>'
noremap! <expr> <LeftMouse> getmousepos().winid==win_getid() ? '<LeftMouse>' : '<Cmd>call win_gotoid(getmousepos().winid)<CR>'
```

It checks if the focused window is the one under the mouse, and if so it left clicks as normal.
If the window under the mouse is not the one that is focused, it calls the function to change the the current window to the window under the mouse.
This couldn't be done with a normal `<exec>` command because you can't change the cursor position from within the `<exec>`. It had to be called using `<Cmd>`.

Comment: If it works for you it would be good if you could accept it using the v button next to the arrows voting buttons. It allow the question to rest (you'll have wait two days for that)

Comment: I will, but it won't let me until tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You can set the option `mousefocus`

```
:set mousefocus
```

When you move the cursor on the window the window is activated but the cursor is not changed (not exactly what you ask but close).

You can use the mouse wheel to scroll the window.

Remark: It seems that it doesn't work yet in nvim-qt see the following [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/41623/23502) for more details.

Remark: Although `mousefocus` is not working `mousescroll` is. This mean that you should be able to scroll your buffer by using the scroll button of your mouse when you move the mouse pointer over the corresponding window (again not what you ask but a consolation gift)

Comment: This seems like the way to go, but it doesn't do what it says it does. Will add my setup to the question

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you elaborate why you believe: *it doesn't do what it says it does*?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it has no effect

Comment: Did you tried with `gVim -u NONE -i NONE`?

Comment: I'm not using gVim, I'm using Neovim with Nvy

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have the same problem with Neovim :-/